# Show fragment call onResume?

Tags: android, android-fragments

After I call fragmentTransaction.show(fragment) on a fragment, what will happen to the fragment? Which callback methods of the fragment will be called ? It seems that onResume is not called.
The same question with hide(fragment).

According to the Android [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), onResume is only called if the fragment is added.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement the method `public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden)`.

When you call `fragmentTransaction.show()` , `onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden)` will be called. `hidden` identified the fragment is showing or not.

Answer (score 0):

Im doing like this, and works for now

```
    private void showFragment(String fragmentTag){



    initFragment(fragmentTag);

    FragmentTransaction trasaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    FragmentActions fragment =  (FragmentActions) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);


    if(fragment==null ){  


        if(lastFragmentviewed!=null)
           trasaction.hide(lastFragmentviewed);

        fragment = (FragmentActions) newInstance(fragmentTag);  

        trasaction.add(R.id.content_frame,(Fragment) fragment,fragmentTag);  

    }else{



        if(lastFragmentviewed!=null && !lastFragmentviewed.equals(fragment))
           trasaction.hide(lastFragmentviewed);

        if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag)!=null){
            fragment.init();
            trasaction.show((Fragment) fragment);
        }else
            trasaction.add(R.id.content_frame,(Fragment) fragment,fragmentTag);

     }

    lastFragmentviewed=(Fragment) fragment;

    trasaction.commit();



}



   public interface FragmentActions {


public void init();
```

}

Comment: This does not answer my question. When you call trasaction.show((Fragment) fragment), is the onResume method in the fragment called ?